# intercalate elements of two strings assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, tasm

I have a little problem with my program.
I have to intercalate the elements of two strings,so if i have

S1: 1, 3, 5, 7
S2: 2, 6, 9, 4

it will result D: 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 9, 7, 4.

This is what i did so far, and i have no idea how to fix it, any help please?

```
assume cs:code, ds:data

data segment
s1 db '1357'
s2 db '2694'
l1 EQU ($-s1)
l2 EQU ($-s2)
d db (l1+l2) dup (?)
data ends

code segment
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax

mov si,offset s1
mov cx,l1
mov bx, 0
frst:
    mov ax,[si]
    mov [di]+[bx],ax
    inc si
    add bx,2
loop frst
mov si, offset s2
mov cx,l2
mov bx,1

scnd:
    mov ax,[si]
    mov [di]+[bx],ax
    inc si
    add bx,2
loop scnd

mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: _"i have no idea how to fix it"_. Fix _what_? You haven't explained what the problem is.

Comment: Shouldn't `l1` be one line higher, so it follows `s1`?

Comment: `mov [di]+[bx],ax` --- you have not set `di` perhaps `mov di, offset d`

Comment: yes, thank you, i forgot that

Comment: it works, i also modified ax from mov [di]+[bx],ax with al

Comment: If you know the inputs are the same length, would it make more sense to use one loop that takes one byte from each src, and writes 2 bytes to the dest?  You could `mov al, [s1+idx] / mov ah, [s2+idx] / mov [dst+idx*2], ax`, since x86 is little-endian.  You'd have better cache locality for the writes to dst, and less loop overhead.  (8086 doesn't have scaled addressing, does it?  So you'd need to increment an index for the src arrays, and increment a dst pointer by two.  Still less loop overhead than your loops).  On a modern CPU, you could use SSE `punpcklbw` to interleave bytes into words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes in the code, firstly

```
s1 db '1357'
s2 db '2694'
l1 EQU ($-s1)
l2 EQU ($-s2)
```

gets the length of `s1` wrong, it should be

```
s1 db '1357'
l1 EQU ($-s1)
s2 db '2694'
l2 EQU ($-s2)
```

Secondly, `di` is used but not initialised, insert

```
mov di, offset d
```

before the first loop. Next, the data arrays are `byte` values defined by `db`, but you are loading and storing `ax` register. This should be the `al` register, as

```
mov al,[si]
mov [di]+[bx],al
```